# Prove that lim $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Here's the question: Prove that lim $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n = 0$

Here's my attempt at a proof. Can someone please verify it or provide suggestions for improvement?

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Pick $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

If $n > N$, $|\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n| = \left|\frac{(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\right| = \left|\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}\right| = \frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}$

Then, $\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}} \leq \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$.

This completes the proof.

Comment: The proof is correct. Note that the equality :
$|\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n| = \left|\frac{(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\right| = \left|\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}\right| = \frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ holds for every $n$ and that the term is positive (so the use of absolute value is superfluous)

Comment: Correct, though it's clearer if you put $\lim\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)$, with the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct!

Another way would be to use the squeeze theorem:
$$
0 < \sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n < \sqrt{n^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{n^2}} - n = \frac{1}{n}.
$$